# Triggers in a Postgresql slave, not affecting primary database

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, replication, wal

What I need to do is to have a replication of my database in which to create some triggers to do stuff in certain events.

At the moment:

- I have a primary database A in postgresql.
- I have just set up a slave database B using WAL.
- So now, B is of course a read only database

The point is that at this point, B is a readonly database, so I can't create my triggers.

Why doing it in a slave? Because I would like to affect as less as possible to the main project using the primary database.

I tried to stop the replication, to create the triggers in B and then start it again. But it never start replicating again, I guess because it detects that the schemas differ... :(

Any idea or alternative to get the same goal? Does it make sense to use a master-master replication? But in this case, will be my triggers created in my "slave" replicated to the "primary" database?

Note: I can't use BDR to replicate becase I have to provide support for  postgresql 9.0

Comment: The answer is simple: you can't do this. The slave is read-only. Any change you want to see on the slave needs to be done on the master. What is the _real_ problem you are trying to solve? What are those triggers supposed to do that you think they would negatively impact your master?

Comment: Even if you created the triggers on the master, they wouldn't fire on the replica. Triggers are ignored on replicas when using built-in replication. You can only do this with something like Londiste and an `ENABLE REPLICA` trigger.

Comment: @CraigRinger if triggers are ignored in replication, then master-master looks like an alternative way for it right? I am just thinking out loud...

Comment: What's "BRB"? Why would you need multimaster? What multimaster solution would you be thinking of? I've already said what you need to do if you really want this. Use a trigger-based replication solution like Londiste, Bucardo, etc, and use `ENABLE REPLICA` triggers.

Comment: BRB -> BDR. Sorry, It was a typo